# A new PI prime number?

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers

A Pi prime is a prime number formed from the first n digits of the decimal expansions of constant PI=$3.14159265358979$...The largest such prime we know is $78073$ digits, which is the first $78073$ digits of Pi forms a prime number, see https://oeis.org/A060421. But guess what, I just got this news that the first $613373$ digits of Pi is a probable prime ! see http://www.primenumbers.net/prptop/latest.php. Is there any other such primes between $78073$ and $613373$ ? PI($78073$) is discovered in $13$ july $2006$ by Eric Weisstein as Prprime , so it's a Decade ago !!)

Comment: There's no inherent significance to these numbers, so there's probably no better way of finding them by brute force.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://oeis.org/A060421 has 78073 and 613373 but no others in between. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegerSequencePrimes.html reports that there are no others between 78074 and 205248 but doesn't say anything about the range 205249 to 613372.

Comment: Adrian Bondrescu who discodered $613373$,  just submitted $613373$ to oeis a very moment ago, waw that fast ! : )

Comment: @ditukditun: Probably Adrian would be a better source for the current bounds of this search.

Comment: Since $613373$ has been submitted to oeis. So I think it is clear that there are no others between them : )

Comment: @ditukditun: That's what it's supposed to mean -- otherwise it should have been a comment "613373 is also in this sequence" or "a(8) <= 613373". And I don't imagine a person would find an isolated term of this sequence without searching the preceding (easier) terms.