# Finding Primes in Pi

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, prime-numbers, pi

Consider the numbers of the form
$$
a_n=\lfloor\pi\times 10^{n-1}  \rfloor,
$$
for $n\in\mathbb{N}$. In other words, $\{a_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is the sequence composed of integers built from the first $n$ digits of $\pi$, so that
$$
a_1=3,\,\,\,a_2=31,\,\,\,a_3=314,\,\,\,a_4=3141,\,\,\,a_5=31415,\,\,\,...
$$
My question is: for which values of $n$ is $a_n$ a prime number?

I wrote a small code to find primes for $1\leq n\leq 10^4$, and I've only found primes for $n\in\{1,2,6,38\}$, which are, respectively,
\begin{align}
a_1&=3\\
a_2&=31\\
a_6&=314159\\
a_{38}&=31415926535897932384626433832795028841
\end{align}
I found this result rather intriguing, since I'd expect to find more primes up to numbers with $10^4$ digits. Are there any more primes in this sequence? Is there an explanation for the lack of primes between $a_{38}$ and $a_{10^4}$?

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1809970/a-new-pi-prime-number

Comment: Did you try the same for *e*?

Comment: @stackzebra, no I did not.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is not so few.  If we take the probability that a number $n$ is prime to be $1/\log(n)$, we would expect $\sum \frac 1{n \log (10)}\approx \frac 1{2.3}(\log(n)+\gamma)$ of them out to $n$.  If we do the sum from $2$ to $10^4$ it is $3.8$ while we have $3$ and if we do it out to $16208$ we should have $4$ and we do.  The sum diverges, so we should have infinitely many, but it diverges *very* slowly.

Answer (score 17):

See https://oeis.org/A005042

There you can find out that [Martin Gardner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin_Gardner) first asked  [Neil Sloane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neil_Sloane) [this question](https://oeis.org/A005042/a005042.pdf).

The next term consists of the first 16208 digits.

A naive probabilistic argument suggests that the sequence is infinite.

Comment: Since your "naive argument" suggests the opposite of Ross's heuristic, why not tell us what it is?

Comment: @GEdgar I think the naive argument I refer to agrees with what  Ross Millikan writes. The argument isn't mine - that's a quote from the OEIS page, where you can pursue a link.

Comment: And of course the linked entry [A060421](https://oeis.org/A060421) shows the _lenghts_ of the next terms.

Answer (score 6):

Other answers are much better, but at the very least, $a_n$ ending in 0, 2, 4, 5, 6, or 8 cannot be prime. For the roughly uniformly distributed digits of $pi$, that is 60% nonprime. Have not checked, but probably divisibility rules for 3 and 11 will also kick in.

(Going further/serious means working with distribution of primes, and that is [Ross Millikan's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3362917/374662).)

Comment: Very good point. Thank you!